# how to create an sql view based on calculated vales?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hie lets assume we have the following table

```
TABLE NAME : DRINGE
__________________________________________________

ID  PRODUCT MACHINE MASS    STATE
01  1.76ann HRB 50  inlet
02  1.76ann HRB 38  inlet
03  2.55ann GUDO    45  outlet
04  95mm x 4    GUDO    36  dispatched
___________________________________________________
```

And the following formula:

```
(inlet –outlet ) +outlet – dispatched = [resulted displayed to new view]
```

---

And the values to be substituted are:

---

```
INLET = 50 , 38
OUTLET=45
DISPATCHED = 36
```

---

So substituting in the above formula

```
[(inlet –outlet ) +outlet – dispatched = [resulted displayed to new view]
```

We get this

```
(50+38 – 45 ) + 45 – 36 = 52
```

What I want is for the result ie 52 to be displayed in an sql view  like the following view

```
Dringe VIEW
_____________
Total_summary|
_____________|
 52          |
_____________|
```

.
Does anyone have any idea of an sql query I can use to do this ? 
I rily need your help am stuck again, thanx in advance.

Comment: MySQL? SQL Server? Which one are you using?

Comment: First of all, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?. And why are you adding outlet and substracting outlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will follow your formula

```
CREATE VIEW DRINGEView AS 
SELECT sum(case when state = 'inlet' then mass else 0 end) - 
       sum(case when state = 'outlet' then mass else 0 end)+
       sum(case when state = 'outlet' then mass else 0 end) -
       sum(case when state = 'dispatched' then mass else 0 end) AS Total_summary
FROM dringe
```

But adding outlet then subtracting outlet would be redundant. The brackets in your formula would also be redundant as all of your operators are addition/subtraction, could one of your operators be multiplication/division?

Comment: yes can use multiplication/division I really appreciate your help , and what are you suggesting I do instead of using the redundant operators? am trying out your query right now

Answer (score 0):

you can just add those calculations to your query in something like

(40+50+fieldName*anotherFieldName) AS calculation

and you can even use sub tables like

(40+50+(SELECT fieldName FROM anotherTable WHERE someValue) AS calculation

Answer (score 0):

```
create view dringe_view as
select (sum(inlet) – sum(outlet) ) +sum(outlet) – sum(dispatched ) as total_summary
from tab
```

But your claculation can be further simplified (remove outlet - outlet) to (inlet – dispatched)